# Estimation of the yaw angle of a vehicle based on gyrosop, velocity and steering angle with kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am new in this Community and almost new at working with kalman filter, so I ask you to be considerate. I think the solution is very easy, but I'm still stuck since several days. My goal is to estimate the yaw-angle $\psi$ of a car with a kalman filter. Therefor I measure the velocity in x-direction and the steering angle of the front wheels as well as the yaw-rate with a gyroscope. My measurement vector looks like:

$$
z = \left(\begin{array}{c} \hat{\dot\psi} \\ \hat{\delta}  \\ \hat{v} \end{array}\right)
$$

My state vector x is:
$$
x = \left(\begin{array}{c} \dot\psi \\  \psi \\ \delta \\ v \end{array}\right)
$$

Since $v$ and $\delta$ are measured, I wanted to use the following equation from the single-track model:
$$
\dot\psi = \dfrac{1}{R}*v *tan(\delta) 
$$
where $R$ is the wheelbase. Now my problem is simply to include this mathematical relationship into the state space model.
My first try was:
$$
x_{k+1} = \left(\begin{array}{c} \dot\psi_{k+1}\\ \psi_{k+1} \\ \delta_{k+1} \\ v_{k+1} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} \dfrac{1}{R}*v_k *tan(\delta_k)\\  \dot\psi_k *dt+\psi_k \\ \delta_k \\ v_k \end{array}\right)
$$
$$
z_k = \left(\begin{array}{c} \hat{\dot\psi} \\ \hat{\delta}  \\ \hat{v} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} \dot\psi_{k+1}\\ \delta_{k+1} \\ v_{k+1} \end{array}\right) 
$$
but I think this is not valid, because the first equation in $x$ is not a prediction for the next time step. At next I tried to include it in the equations of $z$, but I still didn’t get any further.

Can you please help me, figure out what I'm doing wrong? How should the equations reasonably be? Once I have the equations, the rest should be clear.

Comment: I think your system might not be observable, in which case a Kalman filter won't work.